# Focus application when opening document

Tags: 14.04, filezilla

How do I get gedit to take focus when I select View/Edit file in filezilla in  Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: Not a dup, it opens in gedit - just doesn't focus after doing so. thanks.

Comment: Are you saying the *window* doesn't focus? Sorry, then.

Comment: Correct - if the window is behind other windows it doesn't bounce out in front. np.